Why does (right - left) / 2; cause a segmentation fault?
I have read the following SO post here and understand why I want to use left + (right - left) / 2; vs (right - left)/ 2; to prevent the possibility of a buffer overflow.
I am also curious as to why using the latter can cause a segmentation fault as well, or where that simple change opens up the possibility for the segmentation fault to occur elsewhere.
void mergesort(int arr[], int left , int right){
    if (left<right){
        int mid = (right - left) / 2; // Simply changing this from left + (right - left) / 2 to (right - left) / 2 is causing a seg fault!
        mergesort(arr, left, mid);
        mergesort(arr, mid + 1, right);

        merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
}


#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int arr[], int start, int middle, int end){
    // Find the size for each subarray
    int left_size = middle - start + 1;
    int right_size = end - middle;
    int left[left_size]; int right[right_size];
    
    // Copying over values to the subarrays
    for (int i=0; i < left_size; i++){
        left[i] = arr[start + i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i < right_size; i++){
        right[i] = arr[middle + i + 1];
    }

    // Pointers for the arrays
    int lp,rp, ap;
    lp = 0;
    rp = 0;
    ap = start;

    while (lp < left_size && rp < right_size){
        if (left[lp] <= right[rp]){
            arr[ap] = left[lp];
            lp++;
        }
        else{
           arr[ap] = right[rp];
           rp++;
        }
        ap++;
    }

    while (lp < left_size){
        arr[ap] = left[lp];
        lp++; 
        ap++;
    }
    while (rp < right_size){
        arr[ap] = right[rp];
        rp++; ap++;
    }
};

void printArray(int arr[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {6, 5, 12, 10, 9, 1};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    mergesort(arr, 0, size - 1);

    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    printArray(arr, size);
}


Did int mid = (right - left) / 2 intend to be int mid = (right + left) / 2?

(right - left) / 2 does not compute a value midway between right and left, unless left is 0.

To quickly diagnose segfaults, run the code through gdb or another debugger so you can see where it happens.  In this case, it seems likely you're incorrectly calculating the array offset and end up attempting to access the wrong memory area.

If you indeed understand why left + (right - left) / 2 avoids an overflow that is possible with (right + left) / 2, then you already understand why the latter can lead to a segfault.  Such a segfault is a likely direct consequence of the out-of-bounds access arising from such an overflow.

The specific problem with int mid = (right + left) / 2 may be integer overflow, which can lead to indexing out of bounds.

Re "To quickly diagnose segfaults, run the code through gdb", Or run a build compiled with -fsanitize=address

@WeatherVane for any reasonable definition of int you are extremely unlikely to run into an overflow, no matter how theoretically possible it might be.  It's not the cause of the fault in this question.

@MarkRansom. Yeah, right. The fault was int mid = (right - left) / 2 as in my first comment. What is a "reasonable definition of int" supposed to mean anyway? Do you consider a 16 bit int to be "unreasonable"? Or are you objecting to the well-known left + (right - left) / 2 as being entirely unnecessary? Pshaww! But I do agree that it's not usually an issue.

@WeatherVane yes I consider 16 bit int to be unreasonable, for quite a long time now.  Although I did have a boss that insisted we use long because he'd been burned by Microsoft's definition of int back when 16-bit OS were the rage.  And no matter what your int size is, you won't get in trouble until you're using at least half of it - that's why I said "extremely unlikely" rather than "totally impossible".

@MarkRansom and there lies the beginner's road to bad code: saying "oh that won't happen" instead ensuring "that can't happen". Particularly with C. And the C Standard still allows 16 bit int.

@WeatherVane please don't get me wrong, I'm not arguing that your form isn't better and preferred.  But the only time I've ever seen that be a problem is with artificial test cases that were engineered to expose that problem.  As for 16 bit int, there are probably microcontrollers where that's still standard and I hope I'm never stuck using one of those.

@MarkRansom fair enough, but someone may be using one, and this site should not alienate or belittle them.

@WeatherVane are you speaking of the fact that you lose a bit due to signed arithmetic?  I didn't consider that.

Sorry, I deleted that as incorrect: I was thinking that 16384 + 16384 will overflow signed 16 bit int, 16384 being a quarter of the range.

@WeatherVane no, you were right.  The range of signed 16 bit is -32768 to 32767, 16384+16384 will definitely overflow.

The mathematical equivalent of left + ( right - left ) / 2 is ( right + left ) / 2.
  left + ( right - left ) / 2
= ( 2 * left + right - left ) / 2
= ( left + left + right - left ) / 2
= ( right + left + left - left ) / 2
= ( right + left ) / 2

However, you used ( right - left ) / 2 instead. Notice the incorrect operator.
To diagnose segfaults, run the code through a debugger (e.g. gdb). Alternatively, you could run a build compiled with an address sanitizer (-fsanitize=address with gcc and clang).
